# How to do batch display using NSTextView

Tags: appkit, nstextview

I'd like to be able to show a view that resembles something like a console log, with multiple lines of text that are scrollable and selectable.

The fundamental procedure I have in mind is maintaining an array of strings (call it `lines`) and appending these to the `textStorage` of the `NSTextView` using a new line character as delimiter.

However there are a few factors to consider, such as:

1. Updating the `textStorage` on scroll so that it appears seamless to the user
2. Updating the `textStorage` on resizing the view height
3. Maintaining scroll position after the `textStorage` gets updated
4. Handling an out of memory possibility

Can someone please provide some guidance or a sample to get me started?

Answer (score 1):

Add a string from your array to the `NSTextStorage` and animate the `NSClipView` bounds origin.

```c
- (void)appendText:(NSString*)string {
    // Add a newline, if you need to
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", string];

    // Find range
    [self.textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(self.textView.textStorage.string.length, 0) withString:string];

    // Get clip view
    NSClipView *clipView = self.textView.enclosingScrollView.contentView;

    // Calculate the y position by subtracting 
    // clip view height from total document height
    CGFloat scrollTo = self.textView.frame.size.height - clipView.frame.size.height;

    // Animate bounds
    [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:NSMakePoint(0, scrollTo)];
}
```

If you have elasticity set in your `NSTextView` you need to monitor for its frame changes to get exact results. Add `frameDidChange` listener to your text view and animate in the handler:

```c
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Text view setup
    [_textView setPostsFrameChangedNotifications:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(scrollToBottom) name:NSViewFrameDidChangeNotification object:_textView];
}

- (void)appendText:(NSString*)string {
    // Add a newline, if you need to
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", string];

    // Find range
    [self.textView.textStorage replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(self.textView.textStorage.string.length, 0) withString:string];
}

- (void)scrollToBottom {
    // Get the clip view and calculate y position
    NSClipView *clipView = self.textView.enclosingScrollView.contentView;

    // Y position for bottom is document's height - viewport height
    CGFloat scrollTo = self.textView.frame.size.height - clipView.frame.size.height;
    [[clipView animator] setBoundsOrigin:NSMakePoint(0, scrollTo)];
}
```

In real-life application you would probably need to set some sort of threshold to see if the user has scrolled away from the end more than the height of a line.

Comment: Thanks so much. I’ll give this a go.